# Parameterised constructors in web API not working

Tags: constructor, asp.net-core-mvc, controllers

I am using dot net core web api and I was trying to implement DI. I came to notice that , the moment you declare parameterised constructor the api wont work.

Sample:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
   public ValuesController()
    {

    }
    public ValuesController(string abc)
    {
        abc = "123";
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

I dont know what exactly went wrong...

Comment: Can you start by explaining `...the api wont work`. Please provide all the Exception details or the details of the unexpected behavior if there is no Exception.

Comment: It was not throwing any exception. I was basically getting an Http 500 .

Comment: are you using the app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() page? if you are not, then you should. Also, if you are running from console or from VS\code you will see the exception in the program output window.

Comment: yes..got it.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I just had to configure DI, since proper DI was not configured it was not able to figure out the purpose of the constructor.